# How can I test using jest if branch, if condition value depends on sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have this code to test:

```
selectTab() {
    const tab = localStorage.getItem('moduleTab');
    if (tab != null) {
        this.querySelector('core-tabs').active = {key: 'id', value: tab};
        this.renderTabs(tab);
    } else {
        this.querySelector('core-tabs').active = {
            key: 'id',
            value: 'modules',
        };
        this.renderTabs('modules');
    }
}
```

This is the result of test:

[image]

I am only able to test the else branch, how do you test the if branch?

Answer (score 0):

In order to test the if branch, you need to have a tab equal to null.
To achieve this, you need to clear your app storage which will clean your sessionStorage and then your sessionStorage.getItem('moduleTab') will be null. (I suppose you are not adding the moduleTab anywhere).

Otherwise, you can change the line
const tab = window.sessionStorage.getItem('moduleTab');
to
const tab = null;

You will then test the if branch